# Eclipse Neon - Erro 13

Tags: eclipse

Boa tarde galera...vi diversas formas de alterar o arquivo eclipse.ini mas comigo não funcionou. Alguma dica ?
Win 7 64 bits - Java 8 - eclipse Neon

Comment: Seu eclipse e JDK são 64 bits? tem cara de um deles ser 32 bits

Comment: Sim, 64 bits...

Comment: Valeu rray, baixei o oxygen de 32 bits e rodou

Comment: Pelo jeito sua JDK era 32 bits.

Comment: Sim, 32. Estava confundindo com o SO